# Google Charts - annotationText in a Column Chart

Tags: google-visualization

This question is about the `annotation` and `annotationText` roles in Google Charts. `annotation` shows text near a data point on the chart, and `annotationText` provides a popup tooltip for the annotation.

In a `ColumnChart`, the annotation is placed inside the column if it fits. Otherwise the annotation is placed above the column in a similar way to annotations in other chart types.

When the annotation is above the column, the annotationText works (a tooltip is displayed when you hover over the annotation).  However for annotations inside the column, the tooltip does not appear.

Example over here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hjhsa

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like you've found a bug!  You can file a bug report on it [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list).  Include a description of the problem and a link to your codepen example.

Comment: Thanks, submitted here: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1556

Answer (score 0):

This more than likely has been fixed now, but you could add the following to options.

```
bar: { groupWidth: "95%" }
```